# Array of reference variables

Tags: java, arrays, garbage-collection

I was asked by my text to count the references to an object. Inside the given code was the following:

```
Honey honeypot = new Honey();

Honey [ ] ha = {honeypot, honeypot, honeypot, honeypot};

Bees b1 = new Bees();

b1.beeHA = ha;
```

where the constructor for `Bees` creates the `Honey[ ] beeHA` array.

Now I thought that `beeHA` would now hold the reference `honeypot` in four positions as does array `ha` and that these would be four separate references plus the four from the `ha` array making eight references. But the diagram the book gives as an answer say that the `beeHA` array only points to the `ha` array not to the object referenced by the `honeypot` reference variable making only four references. Am I thinking about this correctly?

If array `ha` were to be garbage collected (subject of the chapter) wouldn't `b1.beeHA[x]` still contain the `honeypot` reference variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ha` isn't an array - it's a variable. The value of the variable is a reference to the array - as is the value of `b1.beeHA`. So it doesn't really make sense to talk about "array `ha`" being garbage collected. When you write:

```
b1.beeHA = ha;
```

that simply copies the value of `ha` into `b1.beeHA`. It's not copying the array - it's just copying the reference.

The code you've shown creates *one* array containing four references to one instance of `Honey`. There are two references to that array - one in the variable `ha` and one in the variable `b1.beeHA`.

Comment: this makes the most sense to me. I suppose i was thinking there were two separate array objects and not just one with two references. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The crucial distinction in the Java type system is between **value semantics** and **reference semantics**: When you say `x = y;`, then *values are copied*, and *references are aliased*.

Primitive types (like `int`) have value semantics; class-types and arrays have reference semantics. So when you say `b1.beeHA = ha;`, you alias the reference to the array, which is to say that now both `ha` and `b1.beeHA` reference the same array.

The garbage collector won't collect the array while there are still references to it.

Comment: Actually, I think even that makes it more complicated than it needs to be. Assignment *always* copies the value of the RHS to the LHS. It's just that if `x` and `y` are of a class type, then the value of the variable is a reference - that's all. There's no *aliasing* going on, in that the `x` and `y` variables aren't tied together - they just happen to have the same value, which is a reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think what you're describing is the implementer's perspective. From the language perspective, there are no "reference types", so your statement cannot really be expressed within in the language itself, if that makes sense. (E.g. the type of `honeypot`, as specified by the Java type system, is really `Honey`, and not some mystaculous "assignable reference to `Honey`".)

Comment: If there are no "reference types" in the language, why is JLS section 4.3 entitled "Reference types and values"? And from section 4.3.1: "An object is a class instance or an array.
The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object." Nothing mystaculous there - it's all in the spec. It differentiates very clearly between references and objects. I can't find your use of the term "alias" in the spec though...

Comment: (And likewise from the start of section 4.1: "There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types
(§4.2) and reference types (§4.3).")

Comment: @JonSkeet: Fair enough. I suppose what I meant is that the type system does not have distinct types `Honey` and "reference to `Honey`". The code suggests that `honeypot` is a variable of type `Honey`, so I find the reasoning in terms of value vs reference semantics rather more systematic; but you're right of course that the JLS does describe reference types.

Comment: Well, there's no way of creating an expression whose value is the object, but the spec clearly differentiates between "an object" and "a reference" (see my earlier comment) - so why not keep that distinction when talking about it? I've found that making the difference between a *variable*, a *value* (a primitive value or a reference) and an *object* makes all kinds of things very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit confusing without more context; I can't see scope on any of these variables.

An object won't be garbage collected if there's an object holding onto a reference to it.  The honeypot reference points to the new instance of Honey; so does the ha array.  The b1 instance points to the ha array.

If you draw an object graph, the b1 instance points to ha, which points to honeypot.

If b1 is garbage collected, then the whole graph is eligible.

The Honey instance won't be GC'd as long as b1 and ha are around.